# Is it possible to pass-through parameter values in Moq?

Tags: c#, testing, mocking, moq

I need to mock `HttpResponseBase.ApplyAppPathModifier` in such a way that the parameter `ApplyAppPathModifier` is called with is automatically returned by the mock.

I have the following code:

```
var httpResponseBase = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
httpResponseBase.Setup(hrb => hrb.ApplyAppPathModifier(/*capture this param*/))
                .Returns(/*return it here*/);
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Found a solution on the first page of Moq documentation (http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart):

```
var httpResponseBase = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
httpResponseBase.Setup(hrb => hrb.ApplyAppPathModifier(It.IsAny<string>)
                .Returns((string value) => value);
```

I suddenly feel a lot stupider, but I guess this is what happens when you write code at 23:30

Comment: I had a need to throw a passed in `Exception` argument.  I used the `Callback()` method (instead of `Returns()`) to throw it.  Just for posterity and completeness.

Comment: @gregsdennis Great! Thanks for posting. Not noticed `Callback()` before - perhaps it was introduced more recently.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `It`:

```
It.Is<MyClass>(mc=>mc == myValue)
```

Here you can check the expectation: the value you expect to receive.
In terms of return, just return value you need.

```
var tempS = string.Empty;
var httpResponseBase = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
httpResponseBase.Setup(hrb => hrb.ApplyAppPathModifier(It.Is<String>(s=>{
           tempS = s;
           return s == "value I expect";
           })))
                .Returns(tempS);
```

Comment: Thanks @Aliostad. Just found the solution answer as well (marking yours as the answer). The solution is is actually on the first page of the Moq documentation. I suddenly feel a lot stupider, but I guess this is what happens when you write code at 23:30...

Answer (score 37):

Yes, you can echo back the argument passed to the method

```
httpResponseBase.Setup(x => x.ApplyAppPathModifier(It.IsAny<string>()))
                .Returns((string path) => path);
```

You can also capture it if you want

```
string capturedModifier = null;

httpResponseBase.Setup(x => x.ApplyAppPathModifier(It.IsAny<string>()))
                .Callback((string path) => capturedModifier = path);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for mocking indexing properties and passing the key to a special "case" method that should be called, for example with *IConfiguration* that uses indexed properties, it can be done like this:

```
private IConfiguration GetConfigurationMock()
{
    var mock = new Mock<IConfiguration>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    mock.Setup(c => c[It.IsAny<string>()]).Returns((string key) => GetConfigValue(key));
    return mock.Object;
}

private string GetConfigValue(string key)
{
    return key switch
    {
        "MyKey" => "MyValue",
        _ => throw new NotSupportedException($"{key} is not supported."),
    };
}
```